Package minted: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.LaTeX
I am trying to typeset the following LaTeX document using the minted package:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{hello world}
    \begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
    \end{minted}{c}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

But I keep getting the following error:
Package minted: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.LaTeX
I've installed python3-pygments
$ sudo apt install python3-pygments

And pygments
$ pip install pygments

but to no avail.
